# Python how can I know the status of a process running on a remote machine?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following Python code which starts a process in a remote windows machine. When I do mstsc to the remote machine and check the list of running processes, I can see the process in the task manager.

Python code running on my laptop:
    stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \ (x86)/Vim/vim72/gvim.exe")

How do I know in Python running on my laptop that the process actually started in the remote machine ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ssh` (whatever it is in your code) provides API to check exit status of the command -- check its docs how exactly it is done. I would expect that if `exec_command()` hasn't raised any exception then the program is started after the function returns. If `exec_command()` waits for the command to finish then use some other function to start the command without waiting for it to end: again read the documentation for the Python package that you are using.

Comment: I have APIs for some devices attached to the remote computer but not for all...if I dont have the API and there is no documentation or Python package/DLL drivers, then can I not run the exe like above and check the state ?

Comment: The native approach on Windows, such as used by [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) and [PsList](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682) is based on RPC access to a system's service controller (e.g. [`OpenSCManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and registry `Perflib` database (e.g. [`RegConnectRegistry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: @user3565150: you have the word `ssh` in your source code. Where does it come from? Is it the [`paramiko`](http://www.paramiko.org/) fork?